# What would have been the price of a loaf of bread in 1645 Amsterdam?

Tags: trade, early-modern, netherlands, price

I want to know how much a loaf of bread would cost in Amsterdam in the year 1645.

Preferably I'd like the pricing of a bakery near the harbor but a comparison of the bread prices between the harbor bakeries and the bakeries in the rural backland of Amsterdam could be interesting.

I've searched online but I didn't find anything. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: "backland" get 1,830,000 Google hits and "hinterland", a compound noun beginning with a German preposition that is not otherwise used in English as far as I know, gets 21,100,000. I don't know that I've ever seen "backland" before, although the meaning is self-explanatory.

Comment: @MichaelHardy To be fair, "Hinterland" is a German word, so the German websites will skew that search result as far as English usage is concerned..

Comment: luckily google already have corpus' split by language for us to look at. Google n-grams places hinterland vastly more common than backland, even moreso than google search results: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hinterland%2Cbackland&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chinterland%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbackland%3B%2Cc0

Comment: omg --- You can restrict the book search to works of _fiction_!! They didn't have that feature last time I checked.

Comment: wtf ???? The Google Books ngram view can restrict a search to works of fiction but an advanced search of Google Books cannot?? https://books.google.com/advanced_book_search

Answer (score 30, accepted):

According to [this database](http://www.iisg.nl/hpw/brenv.php) (specifically the  [spreadsheet file](http://www.iisg.nl/hpw/brenv.xls), column D) **a 100kg of rye bread cost 8.22 guilder in the western Netherlands in 1645**, which should at least give you a rough idea to start with. ([Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VTgeIte2c3VDBITSIuFvyx_bPSPCSInD90cOrP8AD_A/edit?usp=sharing) is the same spreadsheet shared on Google Docs for convenience). Using @JustCal's suggestion of 3lb per loaf, this works out to roughly 0.1 guilder per loaf.

I think your best bet for more info is to look at the work of Jan de Vries, for example the article ["Taxing the Staff of Life:  The Dutch bread tax, 1574-1855"](https://economics.yale.edu/sites/default/files/files/Workshops-Seminars/Economic-History/devries-120423.pdf) and the book [*The Price of Bread: Regulating the Market in the Dutch Republic*](https://books.google.com/books?id=xbSQDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA144).

EDIT: Regarding wages, [this page](http://vanosnabrugge.org/docs/dutchmoney.htm) on "Money in the 17th century Netherlands" claims, "An outdoor laborer earned 6.50 guilders per week... A master carpenter earned 9 guilders per week... Wages did not change for 150 years." I am fairly certain de Vries has more data on wages and I will update if I can track this down.

Comment: As a note, a 3lb loaf of bread is a _really_ big loaf. Most home-baked loaves are 1.5–2lb.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- Aye, but you are a likely weak developer with noodly arms, not a strong sailor!

Comment: @pipe I don't see what spinach has to do with this!

Comment: To provide context, it would be really useful to include the average wage for the time period, otherwise we don't know whether 8 guilders is a huge sum of money or pocket change.

Comment: @vsz I'm not sure that information is easily acquired, but for rough context: Manhattan was bought from the natives for 60 guilders in 1626. So in 1645 8 guilders was definitely worth far more than pocket change. A rough back-of-the-envelope calculation tells me those 60 guilders should be at least a thousand dollars of current value, probably twice or thrice that. That would make 100kg of rye bread somewhere 150 - 400 bucks.

Comment: @vsz In addition, did *Jan Modaal* (=Joe Sixpack) in Amsterdam 1645 actually buy bread, or would they have been more likely to bake their own, with the luxury of buying bread limited to the bourgeoisie?

Comment: @gerrit communal ovens were quite common, and I think mandated in some times and places for fire risk management; but on the other hand day labourers and ship personnel would definitely need somewhere to just buy it.

Comment: @Mast My understanding is that the natives were pretty thoroughly ripped off on that sale, so that might not be a valid comparison.  They of course would not have been familiar enough with Dutch currency to know what a fair price would be.

Comment: "Please do not cite without premission"? Is this a thing?

Comment: @MarioTrucco Yes, when a paper has not been officially published in a peer-reviewed journal, it is common to see a draft like that. Do a web search for "please do not cite" and you'll see thousands.

Comment: @vsz Thanks, made an edit towards including an idea of wages. It looks like 8 guilders might be close to the weekly earnings of a skilled carpenter.

Answer (score 19):

I don't think you're going to find anything *close* to the precision you are asking for here.  And as DevSolar has commented I think you are way off the mark by specifying prices in gold.

I do have one example for you though: In [his Autobiography](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/20203/20203-h/20203-h.htm) Benjamin Franklin recounts his journey as a young man in 1723 from Boston to Philadelphia by way of New York (and accidentally Brooklyn).  He has walked, rowed, sailed etc for days and days. He famously accounts his arrival in Philadelphia as follows (emphasis mine):

> I was very hungry; and my whole stock of cash consisted of a Dutch
> dollar, and about a shilling in copper. The latter I gave the people
> of the boat for my passage, who at first refus'd it, on account of my
> rowing; but I insisted on their taking it. A man being sometimes more
> generous when he has but a little money than when he has plenty,
> perhaps thro' fear of being thought to have but little.
>
> Then I walked up the street, gazing about till near the market-house I
> met a boy with bread. I had made many a meal on bread, and, inquiring
> where he got it, I went immediately to the baker's he directed me to,
> in Second-street, and ask'd for bisket, intending such as we had in
> Boston; but they, it seems, were not made in Philadelphia. Then I
> asked for **a three-penny loaf**, and was told they had none such. So not
> considering or knowing the difference of money, and the greater
> cheapness nor the names of his bread, I bade him give me three-penny
> worth of any sort. He gave me, accordingly, three great puffy rolls. I
> was surpris'd at the quantity, but took it, and, having no room in my
> pockets, walk'd off with a roll under each arm, and eating the other.
> Thus I went up Market-street as far as Fourth-street, passing by the
> door of Mr. Read, my future wife's father; when she, standing at the
> door, saw me, and thought I made, as I certainly did, a most awkward,
> ridiculous appearance. Then I turned and went down Chestnut-street and
> part of Walnut-street, eating my roll all the way, and, coming round,
> found myself again at Market-street wharf, near the boat I came in, to
> which I went for a draught of the river water; and, being filled with
> one of my rolls, gave the other two to a woman and her child that came
> down the river in the boat with us, and were waiting to go farther.

Philadelphia in 1723 is not Amsterdam in 1645 but you get the general idea... (at least we are near a harbour): bread is sold by the penny not the gold piece.

Some things to note:

The price of bread in Philadelphia is substantially lower (3x?) than in his native Boston.

The *types* of bread offered in the two places is different, this may make your comparisons difficult even if you find the data.

Comment: Some figures from early colonial days concerning both wages and bread prices  can be found [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=O6Y-y3CWltYC&pg=PA4780&lpg=PA4780&dq=new+amsterdam+1640+price+of+bread&source=bl&ots=e2ZORZdzEa&sig=ACfU3U0cgkTO2b5I0wPVawo1ZHq_XHAozw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjI4KKPyr3qAhXV6Z4KHblxB0MQ6AEwAHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=new%20amsterdam%201640%20price%20of%20bread&f=false)

Comment: To convert British coin to Dutch, there's this handy webpage: http://www.pierre-marteau.com/currency/converter/eng-hol.html

Comment: "I went for a draught of the river water;"  Seems unthinkable to drink port water from the Delaware River!

Comment: @M.Viking Seems remarkable but the population of Philadelphia in 1731 is estimated to be just 12,000.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demographics_of_Philadelphia